# How to detect which app I'm in?

Tags: android, phishing

As a user, How to detect which app I'm using?

Let's say that I opened application A. Then, Application A sends me a third party Login Activity from Application B.

How can I know if I'm typing my credentials on a phishing activity from Application A or I'm typing it on the Application B?

The overview screen from Android application can be easy manipulated to mimic Application B.

Comment: Perform an action that an app can't intercept (press the home button, etc) and manually reopen the target app from the home screen.

Comment: I'm a developer want to protect my users. I can't enforce this behavior. In addition, android support multi task. Thus, the app A could be running a activity 2 from App B and when I click on App from home screen App B could be open from scratch (Activity 1).

Comment: @Oximer You can't protect your users from phishing by unrelated applications, except by educating them properly. Or by introducing a second identification factor which is not susceptible to phishing (so nothing knowledge-based).

Comment: On a Browser, you have a the address bar and the locker where you can check the certificate and the signer. As a example, this paper https://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~chris/research/doc/oakland15_uideception.pdf propose a Android UI that indicates which app are you in. In looking for something like that, but native.